# Crossword Compulsions!

Tags: code-golf, crossword

Chris, a cryptic crosswords addict, has a set algorithm for the order in which he solves them.

[image]

We will use the above image as a guide.

1. Chris always starts off with the first across clue, in this case 1 Across. Chris is a capable crossword enthusiast, so it is assumed that he will always know the answer to the clue he is working on.
2. Once Chris completes a clue, he will check for all clues adjoining those he has completed (in the first case, 1 Down, 2 Down and 3 Down) and then complete the clue with the lowest number. If there are no adjoining clues, he would go to step 3.
3. If the clue is such that the next number (as described in Step 3) has both an across clue and a down clue, he will complete the across clue first (100% certainty, this borders on OCD!)
4. If there are no adjoining clues, he will go to the next available clue that's next in number (across or down)
5. Repeat from Step 2 until all clues are completed.

And this is where it comes down to you, dear coders. You have been tasked to create code that can, on being provided with a crossword template, provide output describing the order of clues based on Chris's algorithm for solving it.

The code will accept input of a crossword puzzle template, in the form of a `.` representing a white square and a `#` representing a black square.

**Example**:

```
.....#.........
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
...#...#.......
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
....#..........
##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
......#........
.###.#####.###.
........#......
.#.#.#.#.#.#.##
..........#....
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......#...#...
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.........#.....
```

**Input** can be through: a) a file read of the representation of the crossword, or b) by line input of each line of the crossword, followed by `\n`, with a second `\n` indicating EOF.

And then it will determine the method by which Chris would solve it according to the above algorithm he has described.

**Output** must be in the format of a series of comma separated instructions in the form of `n(A|D)`, where `n` is the clue number followed by `A` for across or `D` for down.

So in the example above (both from the image, and the example template, which are the one and the same), the output would be:

`1A,1D,2D,3D,9A,10A,4D,5D,6D,7D,8D,11A,12A,13A,15A,14D,15D,16A,17A,18D,19D,20A,21D,23A,22D,24A,25D,27A,28A,26D,29A,30A,31A`

Shortest code wins...

**Testing**

You must provide with your submission the code, a byte count, as well as one of the four test cases represented in the `.` and `#` format, as well as the output generated from this input. There are four test cases, the three below as well as the above example template.

Example test cases:

Test Case 1

```
.....#
.#.#.#
...#..
.#.#.#
.....#
##.#..
```

Output: `1A,1D,2D,3D,4A,5A,6A,7A`

Test Case 2

```
.....#..
.#.##..#
.#....#.
...##.#.
.####...
......##
```

Output: `1A,1D,2D,5A,4D,4A,3D,3A,7A,8A,6D,9A`

Test Case 3

```
.........#
#.#.#.#.#.
....#...#.
#...#.#.#.
..###.#.#.
.#....#...
.#####...#
.....###..
```

Output: `1A,2D,3D,4D,5D,7A,8A,9A,10A,11A,11D,12A,13A,6D,14D,15A,16A,17A`

Test Case 4

```
.....#.........
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
...#...#.......
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
....#..........
##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
......#........
.###.#####.###.
........#......
.#.#.#.#.#.#.##
..........#....
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......#...#...
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.........#.....
```

Output: `1A,1D,2D,3D,9A,10A,4D,4A,5D,6D,7D,8D,11A,12A,13A,15A,14D,15D,16A,17A,18D,19D,20A,21D,23A,22D,24A,25D,27A,28A,26D,29A,30A,31A`

Good luck!

Comment: Just to be sure: In your example image, which number is the _fifth_ clue to be compulsively filled? (after 1H, 1V, 2V, 3V)

Comment: @belisarius The image corresponds to the fourth test case. So the fifth clue to be filled would be 9 Across, or as you would put it, 9H :) As The only adjoining clues after the fourth clue is completed are 9 and 10 Across, Chris will be compelled to fill in the lowest clue first...

Comment: Are the bytes considered only on the basis of the code that produces the correct output. IOW, are you penalized on includes, C# namespace + class + Main, and the like in order to have it compilable or is it reasonable to assume that if I write it in C#, or similar, that minimal amount of code would be required?

Comment: @BobbyDigital Well, this is code-golf... I would hope that if you did plan on writing it in C# you would try not to use too many externals... You'd have to count them I'm afraid...

Comment: @WallyWest I thinkg your third example is omitting a `17A` at the end. Also the fourth the `4A` right after `4D`.

Comment: @Howard, thank you for that... I posted this on Meta late one night, so I must have been a little tired and missed those two... Fixed now. +1 to you. You'll have a crack at it?

Comment: In the final test case, why does `4D` precede `4A`, when `1A` precedes `1D`?  Just because it will intersect an already filled square from `10A`?

Comment: Hey @Jonah, to be honest, given this question is now some seven years old, I haven’t looked at it for some time... if there is a mistake, chances are I missed something in the proofing of this original post... possibly due to fatigue as I posted this somewhat late at night... I’ll have a look shortly... thanks for bringing this to my attention...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 154 characters

```
:^,,{.^=46<{;-1}*)}%[.^n?)/zip[0]*]{1,%{,1>},}%:H"AD"1/]zip{~`{1$0=H{{0=}/}%.&$?)\+[\]}+/}%(2/\{0=)[\~\]}$+[]{1${1=1$&},.!{;1$1<}*1<:F~~@|@F-\1$}do;;]','*
```

Input has to be provided on STDIN. The examples yield the following results (check [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIuLi4uLiMuLi4uLi4uLi4KLiMuIy4jLiMuIy4jLiMuCi4uLiMuLi4jLi4uLi4uLgouIy4jLiMuIy4jLiMuIy4KLi4uLiMuLi4uLi4uLi4uCiMjLiMuIy4jLiMuIy4jLgouLi4uLi4jLi4uLi4uLi4KLiMjIy4jIyMjIy4jIyMuCi4uLi4uLi4uIy4uLi4uLgouIy4jLiMuIy4jLiMuIyMKLi4uLi4uLi4uLiMuLi4uCi4jLiMuIy4jLiMuIy4jLgouLi4uLi4uIy4uLiMuLi4KLiMuIy4jLiMuIy4jLiMuCi4uLi4uLi4uLiMuLi4uLiIKCgo6Xiwsey5ePTQ2PHs7LTF9Kil9JVsuXm4%2FKS96aXBbMF0qXXsxLCV7LDE%2BfSx9JTpIIkFEIjEvXXppcHt%2BYHsxJDA9SHt7MD19L30lLiYkPylcK1tcXX0rL30lKDIvXHswPSlbXH5cXX0kK1tdezEkezE9MSQmfSwuIXs7MSQxPH0qMTw6Rn5%2BQHxARi1cMSR9ZG87O10nLCcqCg%3D%3D&run=true)):

```
1A,1D,2D,3D,4A,5A,6A,7A

1A,1D,2D,5A,4D,4A,3D,3A,7A,8A,6D,9A

1A,2D,3D,4D,5D,7A,8D,9A,10A,11A,11D,12A,13A,6D,14D,15A,16A,17A

1A,1D,2D,3D,9A,10A,4D,4A,5D,6D,7D,8D,11A,12A,13A,15A,14D,15D,16A,17A,18D,19D,20A,21D,23A,22D,24A,25D,27A,28A,26D,29A,30A,31A
```

Comment: +1 Remarkably succinct. How does it work?

Comment: Wow, thanks for making it clear that I should not even waste my time. Clearly going to have to get on top of a more appropriate language. `votes++`

Comment: @BobbyDigital I meant no disrespect. C# is a very verbose language... it's probably not the best for code golf. Code-bowling or for popularity contests on here... but Code Golf is a whole new kettle of fish.

Comment: +1 here too... Probably one of the longer GolfScript entries I've seen... Nicely done.

Comment: @WallyWest: None taken. Yes it is, I was still going to try, that is, until I saw Howard's.  It's the first I've heard of GolfScipt. As soon as I get some free time I'm going to give it a go and come back.

Comment: @BobbyDigital: The task itself is quite interesting. Give it a try in a language you are familiar with. I think you'll enjoy the puzzle as much as I did - investigate all the different approaches to tackle the puzzle. It is fun by itself even if you don't reach a character count as low as this answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>806</s> 477

(There appears to be a glitch in the ordering of the solution steps.  I am looking into this.)

### Golfed

The function `q` finds the order of the crossword solutions.

```
i = Dimensions; v = MemberQ; u = Position; y = ToString; k = Select;
q@t_ :=
 (g@p_ := Characters@StringSplit[p, "\n"];
  w = g@t;
  a[{r_, c_}, z_] := (c != i[z][[2]]) \[And] 
    v[u[z, "."], {r, c + 1}] \[And] ((c == 1) \[Or] 
      v[u[z, "#"], {r, c - 1}]);
  b@z_ := k[u[z, "."], a[#, z] &];
  d[{r_, c_}, z_] := (r != i[z][[2]]) \[And] 
    v[u[z, "."], {r + 1, c}] \[And] ((r == 1) \[Or] 
      v[u[z, "#"], {r - 1, c}]);
  e@z_ := k[u[z, "."], d[#, z] &];
  Cases[Flatten[{
       If[v[b[w], #[[1]]], y[#[[2]]] <> "A"],
       If[v[e[w], #[[1]]], y[#[[2]]] <> "D"]} & /@ (MapIndexed[List, 
        b[w] \[Union] e[w]] /. {{r_, c_}, {i_}} :> ({r, c} -> i))], 
   Except[Null]])
```

---

### Ungolfed

```
q[t7_]:=
Module[{d,acrossSquareQ,acrossSquares,downSquareQ,downSquares,m,numberedCells},
(*w=g[t7];*)
g[p2_]:=Characters@StringSplit[p2,"\n"];
w=g[t7];
acrossSquareQ[{r_,c_},z_]:=(c!=Dimensions[z][[2]])\[And]MemberQ[Position[z,"."],{r,c+1}] \[And]((c==1)\[Or]MemberQ[Position[z,"#"],{r,c-1}]);
acrossSquares[z_]:=Select[Position[z,"."],acrossSquareQ[#,z]&];
downSquareQ[{r_,c_},z_]:=(r!=Dimensions[z][[2]])\[And]MemberQ[Position[z,"."],{r+1,c}] \[And]((r==1)\[Or]MemberQ[Position[z,"#"],{r-1,c}]);
downSquares[z_]:=Select[Position[z,"."],downSquareQ[#,z]&];
numberedCells[z_]:=acrossSquares[z]\[Union]downSquares[z];
m=MapIndexed[List,numberedCells[w]]/.{{r_?IntegerQ,c_?IntegerQ},{i_?IntegerQ}}:> ({r,c}-> i);
Cases[Flatten[{
If[MemberQ[acrossSquares[w],#[[1]]],ToString[#[[2]]]<>"A"],
If[MemberQ[downSquares[w],#[[1]]],ToString[#[[2]]]<>"D"]}&/@m],Except[Null]]]
```

---

`board` displays the crossword puzzle.  The code is not included in the character count. Several sub functions from `q` are borrowed here.

```
board[p_]:=
Module[{q,g,w,downSquareQ,downSquares,acrossSquareQ,acrossSquares,numberedCells,m},
downSquareQ[{r_,c_},z_]:=(r!=Dimensions[z][[2]])\[And]MemberQ[Position[z,"."],{r+1,c}] \[And]((r==1)\[Or]MemberQ[Position[z,"#"],{r-1,c}]);
downSquares[z_]:=Select[Position[z,"."],downSquareQ[#,z]&];
acrossSquareQ[{r_,c_},z_]:=(c!=Dimensions[z][[2]])\[And]MemberQ[Position[z,"."],{r,c+1}] \[And]((c==1)\[Or]MemberQ[Position[z,"#"],{r,c-1}]);
acrossSquares[z_]:=Select[Position[z,"."],acrossSquareQ[#,z]&];
numberedCells[z_]:=acrossSquares[z]\[Union]downSquares[z];
g[p2_]:=Characters@StringSplit[p2,"\n"];
w=g[p];
m=MapIndexed[List,numberedCells[w]]/.{{r_?IntegerQ,c_?IntegerQ},{i_?IntegerQ}}:> ({r,c}-> i);
Grid[ReplacePart[w,m],Dividers->All,Background->{None,None,(#-> Black)&/@Position[w,"#"]}]]
```

---

### TestCases

**1**

```
t1=".....#
.#.#.#
...#..
.#.#.#
.....#
##.#..";
board[t1]
q[t1]
```

[image: t1]

> {"1A", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4A", "5A", "6A", "7A"}

---

**2**

```
t2=".....#..
.#.##..#
.#....#.
...##.#.
.####...
......##";

board[t2]
q[t2]
```

[image: t2]

> {"1A", "1D", "2D", "3A", "3D", "4A", "4D", "5A", "6D", "7A", "8A", 
>   "9A"}

---

**3**

```
t3=".........#
#.#.#.#.#.
....#...#.
#...#.#.#.
..###.#.#.
.#....#...
.#####...#
.....###..";

board[t3]

q[t3]
```

[image: t3]

> {"1A", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7A", "8D", "9A", "10A", "11A", "11D", "12A", "13A", "14D", "15A", "16A", "17A"}

---

**4**

```
t4=".....#.........
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
...#...#.......
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
....#..........
##.#.#.#.#.#.#.
......#........
.###.#####.###.
........#......
.#.#.#.#.#.#.##
..........#....
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.......#...#...
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.
.........#.....";

board[t4]


q[t4]
```

[image: t4]

> {"1A", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4A", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9A", 
>   "10A", "11A", "12A", "13A", "14D", "15A", "15D", "16A", "17A", "18D", 
>   "19D", "20A", "21D", "22D", "23A", "24A", "25D", "26D", "27A", "28A", 
>   "29A", "30A", "31A"}

Comment: I think you have an issue with your code. E.g. in example 2 the `3A` should no be right after the `2D` because there is no clue yet. Also the other solutions show this effect.

Comment: Howard, I am not understanding your point. From "4. If there are no adjoining clues, he will go to the next available clue that's next in number (across or down)", it appears that 3A may be after 2D.

Comment: But e.g. `5A` has a clue and should therefore be favoured over `3A`.

Comment: You've defined a shorthand for `ToString` twice

Comment: Howard, Now I understand your point. Thanks. Will correct later.

Comment: belisarius, thanks, that's the first of many edits I will need to do.  The others will have to wait for now, due to other pressing tasks.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Nice work so far... Can't wait to see the finished result.